# Bulb remaining life Calculate. Exponential Distribution, BUT want exact value instead of probability

Tags: r, sas

Suppose the lifetime of an bulb can be modeled with an exponential distribution with parameter 1.

What is the expected value of a bulb’s remaining life if it has already survived 2 hours?

Comment: This is not a question about programming so it does not belong on Stack Overflow. If you have questions about statistical distributions, you should ask over at [stats.se]

Answer (score 1):

Exponential distribution is memoryless. Therefore, the time that has passed so far is irrelevant, and the expected value of the bulb’s remaining life is 1 (as the expected value of exponential distribution with parameter c is 1/c).

Comment: I understand that, but the question asked what is the expected remining value of a SPECIFIC bulb and that bulb has survived for 20000 hours already. And the question give me what is ∫xe^(-x) dx so I think that should be used in calculating.

Comment: You can use the memoryless property for that specific bulb as well. For example, the probability that it will survive at least 20,001 hours given that it already survived 20,000 hours satisfies P(X>20,001|X>20,000)=P(X>1) (that is the memoryless property). So you can see that the amount of hours it survived so far doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks! I'll buy it!